# Samba restrictions are stopping any mount

Tags: security, mount, samba, restriction

I have a SAMBA export which I only want users A & B to be able to access.

The smb.conf extract is:

```
    [myshare]
    comment = My Share (restricted)
    path = /myshare
    browsable = no
    writeable = yes
    valid users = A, B
```

and a client fstab of:

```
    //server/myshare  /theshareplace cifs file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,username='A',password='pss' 0 2
```

However I receive the error:

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
```

I have tried manual mount of

```
sudo mount //server/myshare  /theshareplace -o username=A
```

and providing the password at prompt, but still receive the error:

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
```

Comment: Does either user have permission to mount on /theshareplace ?

Comment: Both A and B users are in group named 'sharegroup'. The /theshareplace directory is owned by root user but sharegroup owner wth 770 permissions @rakesh_singh